# Load data files across different tests in Golang

Tags: file, go, path, absolute-path

I have a directory structure like:

```
./gen/items/items.go
./gen/items/items_test.go
./gen/items/data/items.xml
./engine/action/actions_test.go
```

In `items.go` I have a method which is supposed to run once, and populate some data structure with the items loaded from `items.xml`. I do this with an absolute path, which works when the code is running in `items_test.go`, as I assume the current working directory in go test is the package root of the current tested package.

```golang
itemsXMLPath := "./data/items.xml"
absPath, err := path.Abs(itemsXMLPath)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(absPath)
```

You can see here why the absolute path `./data/items.xml` works fine from the `gen/items` dir.

If I run tests in `actions_tests.go`, it tries to use the relative path from `action` and fails because there isn't a `data` dir in `action`.

**When I call my loadFromXML method in `items.go`, I want it to always use the relative path from the `items` dir, which will search the data dir below.**

I assumed since the calling code is in `items.go`, the path will go from there, but it seems it uses the working directory of the test runner or the go runner (if I run main.go).

Is there a way to ensure whether used in a test run, or from a main run, the xml load function uses a relative path from a consistent directory in the repo (e.g., how would I consistently find package root dir when ran from MAIN or a test).

I'm sure there is a way to achieve this without duplicating the test data, or without passing in a relative path to the loadFromXML function, which must be adjusted based on where the method is being called!

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. Pass the filename as an argument. You can also use an actual absolute path (which starts with a slash, not with a dot), but that's obviously not very practical if you ever want to run this code on another machine.

Comment: To explain: there are no packages at runtime, so there is no such thing as "package root" at runtime. Packages are only a thing for *building* the program, not when running it.

Comment: Are those XML files static? If yes, use something like https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice or https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr/

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up just writing a function which can find the root directory from any running folder in the project, and then I can apply the relative path from there. Seems to work running from main, or the test runner.

```
func getRootPath() string {
    dir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Check if already in root directory (e.g. main.go)
    lastSlashIndex := strings.LastIndex(dir, "/")
    cName := dir[lastSlashIndex+1:]
    if cName == "#root-folder-name#" {
        return dir
    }

    // Get parent directory
    parent := filepath.Dir(dir)
    lastSlashIndex = strings.LastIndex(parent, "/")
    pName := parent[lastSlashIndex+1:]

    // If not at root, continue getting parent
    for pName != "#root-folder-name#" {
        parent = filepath.Dir(parent)
        lastSlashIndex = strings.LastIndex(parent, "/")
        pName = parent[lastSlashIndex+1:]
    }
    return parent
}
```

Then I can concatenate this directory with the relative path and use it in `filepath.Abs`

```
itemsXMLPath := getRootPath() + "/folder/path/data/items.xml"
absPath, err := filepath.Abs(itemsXMLPath)
```

Comment: the working directory has nothing to do with the source location.  This only works when you actually execute the code from within the source tree